# How to put Google Map on Angular Material md-sidenav?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am unable to put a Google map on an `md-sidenav`; however, when using the same function in the controller to create the map from coordinate parameters everything works and the map is placed in an `md-card` on the page.

Here is the function that is called to create map in the `div` with `id = "lel-gmap"`:

```
     *$scope.init_map = function(glat, glong){
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(glat, glong);

        var mapDiv = document.getElementById('lel-gmap');

        var gMapObject = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, {
          center: position,
          zoom: 14
        });
        var gMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: position,
             map: gMapObject
          });
     }*
```

Both page and sidenav are using same controller. So when the "`lel-gmap`" div is on full page, it works; when same div is on sidenav I get blank image where map should be - but with "Google" appearing in lower left corner of image!! But no map.

Thanks for any advice
jrz

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing DOM manipulation inside of a controller. Use a directive link function for that.